# Affidavits in English burial records

Tags: england, 17th-century, burial-records

My question is about English 17th century burial records.

At the end of the affidavit information is a date and month like >19Mar>.

Is this the date of death or the signing of the affidavit or could it be the date of burial or even the recording in the parish records?

Comment: the date is of the time Rector entered into Parish Register

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information.

Answer (score 2):

In 1667 and 1678 the English wool trade was in trouble so a law was passed requiring every body would be wrapped in a woollen shroud to help the industry. Remember that everyday folk would not have wooden coffins.
An affidavit had to be sworn at each burial that this had been complied with or a fine was payable.

Any date given would be the date of burial.
Eventually everyone ignored it and the law was repealed.

An affidavit is a statement made where you have 'sworn on the bible' that it is true.